# Need a way to print out lookahead portion of a regex pattern in java?

Tags: java, regex

```
    String test = page;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\W+\\s(?=\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    while(m.find())
         System.out.println(m.group());
```

page string looks something like below:

```
Interest
Unknown Unknown’s 
I do not own or know of any assets that should be listed in this category.
$125
Net value of all Home property (Schedules A through H)
$128
Net value of all Bank property (Schedule I)
$253
Net value of all property (Schedules A through I)
```

I need to store last value lets say 253 how to find it using regex and then save it in a string.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://frightanic.wordpress.com/2007/06/08/regex-match-last-occurrence/

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense compared with your requirements, you should really try harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String s = "Interest\n"
            + "Unknown Unknown’s \n"
            + "I do not own or know of any assets that should be listed in this category.\n"
            + "$125\n"
            + "Net value of all Home property (Schedules A through H)\n"
            + "$128\n"
            + "Net value of all Bank property (Schedule I)\n"
            + "$253\n"
            + "Net value of all property (Schedules A through I)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$)\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

output :

125
128
253

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are asking for is to find the lines containing "$125","$128","$253", etc. and you are only interested in the numbers.

In general, use grouping e.g. (\w+) to extract values not look-ahead.

Try this pattern if the value is always at the beginning of a line:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\$(\\d+)");
```

Comment: Will it search only first line or will go for full string?

Comment: It will match one occurrence, but you can use your Matcher object to iterate through, while(m.find){ //do something with m.group()}